# Needle plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to have a needle plot like in

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "h")
```

but in `ggplot2`. Is there a more or less direct way to do it? Or is that only possible with workarounds via line charts or something like that?

[image: example needle plot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10),
       aes(x=x, ymax=y, ymin=0)) +
  geom_linerange()
```

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: I did it with `geom_segment` in the duplicate question, yours is marginally nicer.