# How to plot multiple time series with a reverse barplot on the secondary axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame having four columns as shown below (here I just put header of my actual data frame):

```
df <- tibble(Date=c("2007-05-01", "2007-05-02","2007-05-03", "2007-05-04", "2007-05-05"), Obs = c(0.16,0.15,0.17,0.19,0.14), Sim = c(0.17, 0.11, 0.21, 0.15, 0.13), Rain = c(0.1, 0.11, 0.04,0.21,0.5))
```

How can I plot the data such that the variables `Obs` and `Sim` are plotted on the primary y-axis and `Rain` is plotted as bars on a reverse secondary axis?

Here is the code I have tried thus far:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Obs, color="red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Sim, color="green")) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(y = Rain), stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 3 - .*0.5, name = "Precipitation (inch)"))
```

Here is my expected output:

[image]

**Edit**: Additionally, how can I insert a legend that corresponds to each line (i.e. Obs, Sim, and Rain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `geom_rect`.

1. Calculate the ratio between the maximum of the primary and secondary axes.
2. Store the maximum of the secondary reverse axis.
3. Plot the rectangles using the `ymin` as the maximum minus the value times the ratio.
4. Set the secondary axis ticks as the maximum minus the values divided by the ratio.

I added a `BottomOffset` parameter you could tweak if you want some extra space at the bottom on the secondary axis. I also went ahead and added the code to change the colors of the axes.

**Edit**: Now with a legend.

```
Ratio <- max(c(df$Obs, df$Sim), na.rm = TRUE) / max(df$Rain)
RainMax <- max(df$Rain,na.rm = TRUE)
BottomOffset <- 0.05

ggplot(df, aes(x=as.Date(Date))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Obs, color="1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Sim, color="2")) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=as.Date(Date) - 0.1,
                xmax = as.Date(Date) + 0.1,
                ymin = (BottomOffset + RainMax - Rain) * Ratio,
                ymax = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio,
                color = "3"),
            fill = "red", show.legend=FALSE) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = (BottomOffset + RainMax) * Ratio, color = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Date", color = "Variable") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3"), 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ BottomOffset + RainMax  - . / Ratio, name = "Precipitation (inch)"),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", "2" = "green", "3" = "red"),
                     labels = c("1" = "Obs", "2" = "Sim", "3"= "Rain")) +
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color = "red"), 
        axis.ticks.y.right = element_line(color = "red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
        axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"), 
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(color = "blue"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: @Campbell - How to insert legends corresponding to each lines (i.e. Obs, Sim, and Rain) in above plot?

Comment: You could look into `facet_grid` or combining them with something like `ggpubr::ggarrange` or the `patchwork` package. I think this would likely be a new question as it notably expands the scope.

Comment: @Campbell- If I want to place multiple plots (e.g. four plots) on single page with common x and y labels and common legends, how can it be done using above code? Also how can we insert text (e.g. 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4') to the bottom left corner of each plot,especially when x-axis is datetime?

Comment: I would recommend posting a new question, with the [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include your sample data, the code you have developed using this answer, a link to this question and clearly indicate using a mock up what you are having difficulty with.  I won't have time to look at it tonight, but someone else might.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make two separate plots and stack them on top of each other. This would be useful for people (myself included) who prefer not to use dual-axis plots.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

df <- tibble(Date = c("2007-05-01", "2007-05-02", "2007-05-03", "2007-05-04", "2007-05-05"), 
             Obs  = c(0.16, 0.15, 0.17, 0.19, 0.14), 
             Sim  = c(0.17, 0.11, 0.21, 0.15, 0.13), 
             Rain = c(0.10, 0.11, 0.04, 0.21, 0.5))
             
# convert data to long format
df_long <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date, 
               names_to = 'key',
               values_to = 'value')
```

### Soil moisture plot

```r
sm1 <- ggplot(data = df_long %>% filter(key != 'Rain'), 
              aes(x = Date, y = value,
                  group = key,
                  shape = key,
                  linetype = key,
                  col = key)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab(expression('Soil moisture, m'^"3"*' m'^"-3")) +
  geom_line(lwd = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_color_brewer("", palette = 'Dark2') +
  scale_linetype_manual("", values = c(NA, 'solid')) +
  scale_shape_manual("", values = c(19, NA)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line()) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(3, 'lines')) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(NA, 1),
                                                  alpha    = 1.0,
                                                  shape    = c(19, NA)),
                              nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
```

### Precipitation plot

```r
prec_long <- df_long %>%
  filter(key == 'Rain') %>% 
  rename(Precipitation = matches("Rain"))

maxPrec <- 1.1 * max(prec_long$value, na.rm = TRUE)

p1 <- ggplot(data = prec_long, aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
  # use `geom_linerange` to mimic `type = h` in Base R plot
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139878/needle-plot-in-ggplot2
  geom_linerange(aes(x = Date,
                     ymin = 0,
                     ymax = value),
                 color = "#2c7fb8",
                 size = 10) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab(paste("Precipitation (mm)", sep = "")) +
  scale_x_date(position = "top") +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(maxPrec, 0)) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

### Stack two plots on top of each other

```r
### `cowplot` or `egg` package would work too
# install.packages("patchwork", dependencies = TRUE)
library(patchwork)
p1 / sm1 +
  plot_layout(nrow = 2, heights = c(1, 2)) +
  plot_annotation(title = "My plot",
                  subtitle = "Precipitation and Soil moisture")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This gives me more freedom in terms of changing each individual plot panel. Thanks