# How can i add an upside down bar chart to my ggplot time-series plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, styling

I am trying to make [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v86ee.png) more reader friendly  by adding an upside down bar chart for the "TP" (= total precipitation) variable. Unfortunately I can't get  the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091472/how-to-plot-multiple-time-series-with-a-reverse-barplot-on-the-secondary-axis-us) thread to look any good for me. I would like for the end result to look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkOL5.png), but with lines instead of points. The idea is to make it look less cluttered, but still visualize possible connections between the variables (the usual timespan will be longer than the snippet given below). Here is the str of the original data:

```
> str(DFSub0716)
'data.frame':   1633 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2016-07-06 12:00:00" "2016-07-06 13:00:00" "2016-07-06 14:00:00" "2016-07-06 15:00:00" ...
 $ Q_m3.s  : num  0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 0.396 ...
 $ No3_mg.l: num  1.72 1.5 1.49 1.49 1.48 ...
 $ TP      : num  0.09661 0.06568 0.1311 0.0337 0.00211 ...
```

Edit: Here is some data to reproduce the output from the code below

```
                datetime Q_m3.s No3_mg.l         TP
6703 2016-07-06 06:00:00 0.4430 1.566312 0.01118792
6704 2016-07-06 07:00:00 0.4195 1.609813 0.02158611
6705 2016-07-06 08:00:00 0.3960 1.628437 0.05844045
6706 2016-07-06 09:00:00 0.3960 1.683905 0.04606792
6707 2016-07-06 10:00:00 0.3960 1.617095 0.07120785
6708 2016-07-06 11:00:00 0.3960 1.634220 0.08015819
6709 2016-07-06 12:00:00 0.3960 1.724347 0.09661102
6710 2016-07-06 13:00:00 0.3960 1.495940 0.06567970
6711 2016-07-06 14:00:00 0.3960 1.488123 0.13109615
6712 2016-07-06 15:00:00 0.3960 1.494128 0.03369540
6713 2016-07-06 16:00:00 0.3960 1.482408 0.00210596
6714 2016-07-06 17:00:00 0.3960 1.509152 0.00052649
6715 2016-07-06 18:00:00 0.3960 1.483495 0.00000000
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
#### 2016/07//06
DFSub060716 <- DFSub[DFSub$datetime >= "2016-07-06 06:00:00" & DFSub$datetime <= "2016-07-06 18:00:00", ]

# to long format
library(reshape2)
DFSubL2 <- melt(DFSub060716, id="datetime")
# x-axis breaks
library(lubridate)
desired_breaks2 <- seq.POSIXt(from = lubridate::ymd_hms("20160706 060000"), 
                              to   = lubridate::ymd_hms("20160706 180000"), by = "2 hours")
# scale and plot data
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
NQ060716 <- DFSubL2 %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(
    value.scaled = (value - mean(value)) / sd(value),
    idx = 1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = datetime, y = value.scaled, colour = variable, linetype = variable)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m.%d\n%H:%M", breaks = desired_breaks2)+
  labs(title = "HND low-flow period 2016-07-06")+
  geom_line(lwd = 0.9)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Q_m3.s" = "#000000",
                                "No3_mg.l" = "#669933",
                                "TP" = "#3399FF"))
NQ060716
```

I hope i didn't forget any necessary information, but if so, pls let me know. I am grateful for any help (total beginner here). Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier for people to try out and share potential solutions if you can share some simple example data we can use instead of each having to create our own. That also ensures that the examples we test have the salient features you want them to have.

Comment: I'd probably approach this using `geom_tile()`, which is a little indirect to specify but gives some flexibility in placement over the origin of the axis. It is specified by giving the x and y of its midpoint, plus width and height. If you want it to hang down from 1 to 0.5 on y, you'd specify that it lives at 0.75 ie 1 - 0.5/2  and is 0.5 high.

Comment: I added some data and adjusted the code accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is:
"`scale_y_reverse() +` "

This way you won't need to switch to geom_tile, your example would look like this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = datetime, y = value.scaled, colour = variable, linetype = variable)) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%m.%d\n%H:%M", breaks = desired_breaks2)+
    scale_y_reverse() +
    labs(title = "HND low-flow period 2016-07-06")+
    geom_line(lwd = 0.9)+
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Q_m3.s" = "#000000",
                                "No3_mg.l" = "#669933",
                                "TP" = "#3399FF"))
```