# Make interactive needle plot

Tags: r, plotly

I want to make an interactive needle plot using R package `plotly` similar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139878/needle-plot-in-ggplot2)

By using `ggplot2` and `plotly`, I could easily make an interactive needle plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10),
       aes(x=x, ymax=y, ymin=0)) +
       geom_linerange()
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

However, when the data size is too big, the above code to generate the needle plot become very slow.

I am wondering if I could make the needle plot directly using `ggplotly`.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `add_segments` with specifying `y = 0` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10) %>%
  plot_ly(data = .) %>%
  add_segments(x=~x, xend = ~x, y = 0, yend=~y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>